# Review button/tally does not track actual

Tags: bug

The review queue presents itself across the top like:

[image]

Which when you click on it takes you to:

[image]

The numbers almost always are out of sync with what is in the queue, (the pictures above show 7 whilst all the different categories are empty - i.e. a real time scenario).

1/2 hour previously it read 4, then bumped up to 9 (but there were 7 new things in the queue - so it should have gone to 11) I deal with those and then came back to see a 7 displayed (implying that I'd only dealt with 2 - when it should have shown 0) and now it has been stuck at 7 for about 20 minutes.

I understand a processing delay, or a lower priority (background) process so I don't expect this to be an absolute status indicator, given how dynamic this site can be, but this seems to me more like sticky behaviour i.e. a bug.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't reflect review items you have already voted on but that still require additional votes.

Comment: That is a partial explanation. I just had a case where it showed that there some to work on (don't remember the #), there were 5,  I worked on the first 4 and it went to 0 and there was still one outstanding but the total disappeared.  When I finished the last one it stayed empty.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed this myself now I've reached 10k and there's a [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) unofficial list of changes with the following entry:

- 2014-04-29: 10K users [now see the total number of pending review tasks in the top bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191638/notify-users-of-possible-reviews-on-toolbar/230726#230726) instead of just pending suggested edits.

Reading through the comments below that answer from Shog9 (a Stack Exchange employee):

> this is everything in review, even stuff that you, personally, can't review. Super-expensive to personalize this - so the alternative is simply not having an indicator. Think of it as... A reminder to encourage your peers to review.

I've noticed the number also stays up if I've skipped anything so I can no longer review it or raise a flag I can't review myself. It's a bit annoying because it makes it easy to miss new suggested edits but sounds like it's something they're not considering changing at the moment for performance reasons.